# How do i snap to an intersection of the edge when locking an axis?

Tags: snapping

What i want to do is pretty simple when using Sketchup : 
[image]

But i can´t seem to do the same on Blender... 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a better alternative but you could try **multi point snap**.

Simply press <kbd>A</kbd> while you are snapping to create a snap point. Add multiple points to or near the location you want to snap to to increase the influence of where your vertex will snap. In this case adding a point below and above where the Y axis crosses the edge will give you a close approximation, requires some fiddling to get used to but should be useful.

[image]